# Is there a way to get the current sprint name using the VersionOne API?

Tags: versionone

I know that `Sprint` in the UI maps to the underlying [asset types](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Concepts/Asset_Type) called `Timebox`. And I know I can get the `Name` of a `Timebox` using the [rest-1.v1/Data endpoint](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData):

```
<Server Base URI>/rest-1.v1/Data/Timebox?sel=Name&page=10,0
```

When I examine the [metadata](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/meta.v1), I can see that it has `BeginDate` and `EndDate`. Do I have to compare those to `Now()` to get the current sprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can use the `State` of the `Timebox`:

```
<Server Base URI>/rest-1.v1/Data/Timebox?where=State.Code='ACTV'&sel=Name,StartDate,EndDate,State
```

This depends on using the UI to properly [close completed sprints](https://community.versionone.com/Help-Center/Version101/Current/Sprint-Iteration-Review/Close_Sprint%2F%2FIteration) and activate the next one.